# How can I select a line in the macOS terminal with keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: macos, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal.app

I've recently just switched over to macOS from Windows and I previously used PowerShell. In PowerShell, I could type out a command and hit `ctrl/command a` and it would select whatever I wrote, so that I could copy/delete it.

When I press `command a` in the macOS terminal, it selects the whole window and doesn't let me copy/delete the line I was writing.

Anybody know how to just select what's written and copy/delete it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Emacs-style shortcuts

To delete all you've written, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>.

If you are at the start of the line, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>.

To copy text, you can use the kill ring:

- Type something in your terminal
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> to delete everything (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>)
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> to paste (“yank”) what you've just deleted

These are some of the [Emacs keybindings](https://jblevins.org/log/kbd) that macOS implements for (most) text fields. There are plenty of those, and it's very useful to learn them, since with the additional <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, you have access to more navigational shortcuts.

Note that the copy-paste operation described above does *not* use the system clipboard. To select the entire line, you can triple-click it. But this will also include any prompt prefix (e.g., `$`) that you might have configured.

#### Alternative: iTerm2

I'd ditch Terminal.app and use [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/) instead. Apart from many other features that Terminal.app does not have, it offers [*Copy Mode*](https://iterm2.com/documentation-copymode.html) (<kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>), which allows you to use your keyboard to make selections.

For example, you can:

- Press <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>
- Press <kbd>v</kbd> to select and the entire line
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> or <kbd>y</kbd> to copy the selection
- Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to leave copy mode

Now your native macOS clipboard will have the contents of what you just copied.

Comment: How to select text in terminal with mouse?

Comment: @VityaSchel Just drag over the text you want to select. Does this not work? If so, please give more details and ask a new question.